# Scrollable table body using bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using  **Bootstrap-4** I am not able to apply scroll for table body with fixed header.
I am using min-height as well as overflow for applying scroll to table body.
Does bootstrap4 doesn't support scroll on table body?
Below snippet explains the problem more clearly.

Am I going wrong somewhere?

```css
.tbody {
  min-height:10px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
          
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want the scroll to be horizontally?

Answer (score 8):

After setting `display:block` property to table you can set height and widths.

**Try this:**

```
table {
  display:block;
  height : <set your desired height>;
  overflow-y : scroll;
}
```

Comment: If I was OP I would have checked this as answer 

Comment: It's unfortunate that `display:block` is needed as this makes the table look bad in some instances. I've tried it without block and with others but `display: block` is the only option here. CSS is such a pain.

Comment: this will also scroll the header too, so no! this is not the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were looking for

```css
.tbody {
  height: 50px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
   
.my-tbody {
  height:30px;
  display:block;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:100%;
}

tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
          
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <table class="my-tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <div class="cl"></div>
    </table>
  
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,but the column gets mis -aligned if display block is used

Comment: please see if this is helpful and if not please let me know what kind of scroll and to which elements you want to apply Thanks :)

Comment: i have added another answer for you please take a look

Answer (score -2):

or you can use this .

```css
.tbody {
  height: 50px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}

.my-tbody {
  height:50px;
  display:block;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:100%;
}

tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 33.33%;
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="container">
          
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <table class="my-tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <div class="cl"></div>
    </table>
  
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: columns still don't match table header